# How I can check if my Jquery function finished successfully?

Tags: jquery

I am doing jquery function to do some animation to text paragraphs, I found a good example in Stackoverflow and edited it to meet my needs.

but how can I alert something after last paragraph animation completed ??

you can check my code form the link below

http://jsbin.com/araget/24/edit

```
(function ($) {
  // writes the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param String str
  // @param Numeric cursor
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void
  function typeString($target, str, cursor, delay, cb) {
    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      return html + str[cursor];
    });

    if (cursor < str.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        typeString($target, str, cursor + 1, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // clears the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void
  function deleteString($target, delay, cb) {
    var length;

    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      length = html.length;
      return html.substr(0, length - 300);
    });

    if (length > 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        deleteString($target, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // jQuery hook
  $.fn.extend({
    teletype: function (opts) {
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.teletype.defaults, opts);

      return $(this).each(function () {
        (function loop($tar, idx) {
          // type
          typeString($tar, settings.text[idx], 0, settings.delay, function () {
            // delete
            setTimeout(function () {
              deleteString($tar, settings.delay, function () {
                loop($tar, (idx + 1) % settings.text.length);
              });
            }, settings.pause);
          });

        }($(this), 0));
      });
    }
  });

  // plugin defaults  
  $.extend({
    teletype: {
      defaults: {
        delay: 100,
        pause: 5000,
        text: []
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$('#target').teletype({
  text: [
    'Hi I am ShoBingg!',
    'A Mobile loyalty system that works on your smart phone.',
    'My job is to collect Binggz and redeem it for you so you get awarded!',
    'So what are Binggz?',
    'Binggz are the points you get from your favorite local merchants whenever you shop, dine or even visit!',
    'So you do not have to carry any more cards, I am with you all the time and work with home deliveries and wherever you go.',
    'Happy Rewarding!'
  ]
});

$('#cursor').teletype({
  text: ['_', ' '],
  delay: 0,
  pause: 500
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add another option to your plugin that is a callback in the event that the teletype is about to loop.  E.g. if the option is called `loopCallback`, this example passes in the function `callWhenFinished` containing an alert:

```
(function ($) {
  // writes the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param String str
  // @param Numeric cursor
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void
  function typeString($target, str, cursor, delay, cb) {
    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      return html + str[cursor];
    });

    if (cursor < str.length - 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        typeString($target, str, cursor + 1, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // clears the string
  //
  // @param jQuery $target
  // @param Numeric delay
  // @param Function cb
  // @return void
  function deleteString($target, delay, cb) {
    var length;

    $target.html(function (_, html) {
      length = html.length;
      return html.substr(0, length - 300);
    });

    if (length > 1) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        deleteString($target, delay, cb);
      }, delay);
    }
    else {
      cb();
    }
  }

  // jQuery hook
  $.fn.extend({
    teletype: function (opts) {
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.teletype.defaults, opts);
      var numOfMessages = settings.text.length;

      return $(this).each(function () {
        (function loop($tar, idx) {
          // type
          typeString($tar, settings.text[idx], 0, settings.delay, function () {
            // delete
            if ((idx+1) % numOfMessages === 0)
               settings.loopCallback();    
            setTimeout(function () {
              deleteString($tar, settings.delay, function () {
                loop($tar, (idx + 1) % settings.text.length);
              });
            }, settings.pause);
          });

        } ($(this), 0));
      });
    }
  });

  // plugin defaults  
  $.extend({
    teletype: {
      defaults: {
        delay: 100,
        pause: 5000,
        text: [],
        loopCallback: callWhenFinished
      }
    }
  });
}(jQuery));

$('#target').teletype({
  text: [
    '<a href="a">Hi I am ShoBingg!</a>',
    'Happy Rewarding!'
  ]
});

function callWhenFinished() {
        alert("Finished. Looping...");
}
```

Comment: @ManMann - works for me: http://jsbin.com/araget/40/edit   Note I didn't paste in all of your plugin into the code above - just the bottom part changed. I've edited it and added in all of your code above.